# Digital Goods for Express Checkout (dg.js) not working

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

It was working till yesterday and stopped working as expected. Before the code change, when we clicked a button it would trigger a pop up and it now redirects to another page. We looked into the code and found the issue

`let fullpageRedirect = true;`

there is a variable declaration that never sets to false

url to the [code](https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js)

if we change the code, to

`let fullpageRedirect = false;`

this is working as expected.

I forgot my Paypal password and cannot seem to reset it, I do not get the email or SMS they say they "sent" and this is required for our flow.

I do not want to host the code locally, although that works for now. It would be awesome, if the code was changed on Paypal's side.

Comment: Paypal seems to have fixed this.

Comment: Did the problem just come back as of today?  Our lightbox quit working and starting do full page redirects.  Researched and found always true value at https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js .

Comment: I checked the wayback machine and can see that in early 2018 it was false, then true, then back to false around  Feb 9 as noted above.  But, then shortly after and since then it is back to true.   Seems if this is the issue, that it would be causing a lot of issues for others

Comment: we have self hosted the script for now.

Comment: thanks.  tried self hosting just the dg.js and now getting error...  Refused to display 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?payKey=xyz' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change code on top to let `fullpageRedirect = false;` and it works.